# C --> JS Finding equivallency

Tags: javascript, c

I'm rewriting a C program in Javascript, and need some help.

What is the equivalent form of this fragment in Javascript?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    float a[100], b[100], c[100];
    float p = 0.4;
    float q = -0.3;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i<100; i++)
    {
        a[i] = ((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)*2-1;
        b[i] = ((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)*2-1;
        if(((a[i]*p)+q)>b[i])
            c[i]=1;
        else
            c[i]=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know that declaration is by "var". The main focus of my question is on `srand()`
and body of the for-loop.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: This function doesn't do anything. It just returns `0`. What are you expecting as output?

Comment: It doesn't matter what it does, it's just fragment of code .. one fuction of many other. I need to work out other functions based on this because I need to work with those vectors, but I don't know how to rewrite random attributes in JS

Comment: Note that the declarations of `a`, `b`, and `c` are *incomplete*; no size has been provided for the array dimensions, and this code should fail to compile.  `srand` "seeds" the random number generator; it's using the current time as the seed value so you'll get a different sequence each time you run.  Based on some quick googling it doesn't look like JS has an equivalent function.

Comment: `for` loops in C and JS are virtually identical in structure.  You'd replace `(float)rand()/RAND_MAX` with a call to `random()` (or `Math.random()`, not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this script you want a list of 100 elements, either 0 or 1, with some distribution based on `p` and `q`.

```
var i, a = [], b = [], c = [], p, q;
p = 0.4;
q = -0.3;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) {
    a[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1; // [-1..1)
    b[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1; // [-1..1)
    c[i] = ((a[i] * p) + q) > b[i] ? 1 : 0;
}

console.log(a, b, c);
```

Example output:

```
[0.7670025620609522, -0.1457756026647985, 0.11549638630822301, -0.40692117577418685, -0.14018189441412687, 0.6789431390352547, 0.21359567437320948, -0.6463590883649886, 0.635084084700793, 0.16841887682676315, 0.9421727736480534, -0.16769473813474178, -0.773137585259974, -0.9995725285261869, -0.3592250579968095, 0.6221610940992832, -0.2500848602503538, 0.9843343454413116, -0.9965787502005696, -0.43941601924598217, 0.38830276764929295, 0.6027725399471819, 0.1948440819978714, -0.049341874197125435, 0.3607929153367877, 0.6881454959511757, 0.1397378551773727, 0.8200737060979009, 0.876977757550776, -0.9673237577080727, -0.322787603829056, -0.60979925096035, 0.13921364629641175, -0.9891942292451859, 0.86638457281515, 0.27007648907601833, -0.7488472787663341, -0.9241186371073127, 0.6836890983395278, 0.6266482099890709, -0.308770545758307, 0.07420301670208573, -0.9304828280583024, 0.3835716722533107, -0.8057645293883979, 0.2439949233084917, -0.5151346959173679, 0.42057509534060955, 0.6979646165855229, 0.07005349639803171, -0.5269683101214468, -0.8395327562466264, -0.4972861432470381, -0.10812001721933484, 0.30262168822810054, 0.401292173191905, -0.2710290253162384, -0.1065825941041112, -0.70982900634408, -0.17921217950060964, -0.7063160953111947, -0.7673014192841947, 0.9985849163495004, -0.25960679398849607, -0.656108305323869, -0.6723429742269218, 0.7513307207264006, -0.9832490235567093, -0.5018009869381785, -0.46279247058555484, -0.6981143676675856, 0.4598967279307544, -0.9791047847829759, 0.2109047886915505, 0.3666638950817287, -0.016355608124285936, 0.45835994370281696, -0.37226290721446276, -0.4291820954531431, 0.5512992842122912, -0.19488249719142914, 0.258925202768296, -0.766985151451081, -0.029827408958226442, -0.6706948191858828, 0.4848854565061629, 0.5534109445288777, 0.9946446144022048, -0.9731632391922176, 0.3055804814212024, 0.4751733224838972, -0.16723364451900125, -0.2483567874878645, 0.40599026856943965, -0.35266255866736174, 0.8134725908748806, 0.6665135598741472, -0.5901543204672635, -0.9045349485240877, 0.5827030157670379]
[0.08133856160566211, 0.8395420317538083, -0.41627157619223, 0.3680079369805753, -0.38913908367976546, 0.1778678558766842, 0.3973436583764851, -0.5279131387360394, -0.5435993727296591, -0.6946132276207209, 0.39448272343724966, -0.6910627018660307, 0.9589818981476128, -0.7577959052287042, -0.26370000652968884, 0.23077059630304575, 0.18792050145566463, 0.5075835944153368, -0.9592301780357957, 0.22160189552232623, -0.0630328725092113, 0.8887002044357359, 0.20028277393430471, -0.39481773553416133, 0.008400167804211378, 0.45727734360843897, 0.36272056959569454, -0.7925910889171064, 0.5218838006258011, 0.1668773232959211, 0.9676476884633303, 0.8068481837399304, -0.8950712741352618, -0.18899722723290324, -0.24254200095310807, 0.21078301453962922, -0.8083113767206669, 0.9293432626873255, 0.3767823176458478, -0.158718123100698, -0.015238809399306774, 0.8847366087138653, 0.39665115997195244, 0.6991783399134874, -0.8564827470108867, 0.1437798822298646, -0.6003517536446452, -0.14377972157672048, -0.9601167580112815, -0.20674160169437528, -0.18679144140332937, 0.34323167568072677, 0.7899658312089741, 0.0207128943875432, -0.6193350492976606, 0.10440086806192994, 0.14382014889270067, -0.645464095287025, 0.7027792846783996, -0.04367910558357835, 0.1450175540521741, 0.8335230960510671, -0.35647908924147487, 0.35398625768721104, -0.6140687335282564, 0.3962110006250441, -0.4559214115142822, 0.6767970798537135, -0.5526050101034343, 0.8558169966563582, 0.40485234279185534, 0.8315011346712708, -0.13747922657057643, -0.6600476019084454, -0.4200373087078333, 0.23523866711184382, -0.7267463291063905, 0.7958153272047639, -0.967855189461261, 0.39849625807255507, -0.3963926122523844, -0.6662185355089605, 0.11265469435602427, -0.8207298060879111, 0.0518935713917017, -0.6256603212095797, -0.9911297080107033, 0.16159765236079693, 0.9734596558846533, -0.9847397156991065, 0.11539056105539203, 0.035888285376131535, 0.9472811780869961, -0.7288640551269054, 0.044129876885563135, -0.28055421356111765, 0.26336221816018224, 0.41221184050664306, 0.5140346963889897, -0.45493528386577964]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Exactly sir! Thank u !

Comment: @AlexPogue I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. I assumed `rand()/MAX_RAND` gives a number `[0..1)`, so `*2-1` gives `[-1..1)`. If you look at what `p` and `q` do the range is actually very important to the distribution of `0`s and `1`s in `c`. - I don't think the code does `[-1..2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var RAND_MAX = XXX;
var p = X;
var q = X;

function getPLByStackOverflow(){
    function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }

    var a = [];
    var b = [];
    var c = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        a.push(getRandomArbitrary(0, RAND_MAX));
        b.push(getRandomArbitrary(0, RAND_MAX));
        if(((a[i] * p) + q) > b[i])
        {
            c.push(1);
        }
        else {
            c.push(0);
        }
    }

   return (0);
}
```